# JSON-LD error. Missing '}' or object member name

Tags: schema.org

My review schema gives an error:

> Missing '}' or object member name.

See the below schema and screenshot:

```html
<script type="application/ld+json">
    {
      "@context": "https://schema.org/",
      "@type": "Review",
      "itemReviewed": {
        "@type": "Organization",
        "image": "https://www.yarddiant.com/web-development-company.png",
        "name": "Yarddiant",
        
        }
      },
      "reviewRating": {
        "@type": "Rating",
        "ratingValue": "5"
      },
      "name": "I have been working with Yarddiant for few projects and it's been nothing but great experiences by far. They are very professional and extremely responsible everytime I ask for updates or changes on projects. Highly recommended!!",
      "author": {
        "@type": "Person",
        "name": "Johan L."
      },
      
      "reviewRating": {
        "@type": "Rating",
        "ratingValue": "5"
      },
      "name": "Recommend as the best offshore web development company",
      "author": {
        "@type": "Person",
        "name": "Vyshakh S."
      },
      
      "reviewRating": {
        "@type": "Rating",
        "ratingValue": "5"
      },
      "name": "Best Web Support Consultants",
      "author": {
        "@type": "Person",
        "name": "Abel M."
      },
      
      "reviewRating": {
        "@type": "Rating",
        "ratingValue": "5"
      },
      "name": "I have been working in partnership with yarddiant for long term . They are one of the best web development companies that could meet the USA standards.",
      "author": {
        "@type": "Person",
        "name": "Sreesh D."
      },
      "reviewRating": {
        "@type": "Rating",
        "ratingValue": "5"
      },
      "name": "The best web company to work with. Friendly, fast work and the best Quality.",
      "author": {
        "@type": "Person",
        "name": "Rickard B."
      }
      
    }
    </script>
```

You can see the source also:

[image]

Comment: I think the error message about your curly braces is pretty spot on.  Have you tried formatting your code so that they are well balanced?

Comment: "name": "Yarddiant",  ... remove the comma

Comment: That error message should read "found a comma missing object name or do you want the change the comma to a }?" ... the } is not missing!

Comment: @Wayne, why not add that as an answer so it can be accepted (hopefully) and be a useful reference for future visitors.

Answer (score 2):

### The error message is misleading.

I'm posting because that error message should be fixed. The question actually has a typo, addressed in comments.

The message says **"Missing '}'"** and *has caused countless hours of people checking that the '}' which is not missing*.

In fact I've noticed the question have an extra "}"

```
{
  "@context": "https://schema.org/",
  "@type": "Review",
  "itemReviewed": {
    "@type": "Organization",
    "image": "https://www.yarddiant.com/web-development-company.png",
    "name": "Yarddiant",
    
    }
  },
```

should be,

```
{
  "@context": "https://schema.org/",
  "@type": "Review",
  "itemReviewed": {
    "@type": "Organization",
    "image": "https://www.yarddiant.com/web-development-company.png",
    "name": "Yarddiant"
    
    },
```

The comma after the "Yarddiant" is setting up an expectation for another object, but there isn't one instead there is a NOT MISSING '}' and after the object, "itemReviewed" there are more objects. So we need a "},"

The pattern is:

```
{
   "object1": "value1" // no comma because no more objects.
}
// or
{
   "object1": "value1", // comma because there is another object.
   "object2": "value2"
}
```

and values can be {} objects, but the "," exists after the value unless it is the last value.

The "**or object member name**" is more correct.

### The message should say,

### Found '}' when expecting object member name at line number

The '}' is not missing